# Installing latest version of aubio for python

Tags: python, audio, aubio

I installed aubio 0.40 from github. Installation seemed fine. 
But the tests fail.

```
.aubio-master/python/tests/run_all_test 
File ".aubio-master/tests/run_all_tests", line 24, in <module>
unittest.main(defaultTest = 'load_test')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
self.parseArgs(argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
self.createTests()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
self.module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 128, in loadTestsFromNames
suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 113, in loadTestsFromName
test = obj()
File "./tests/run_all_tests", line 19, in load_test
modules = map (__import__, modnames)
File "/home/ajit/aubio-0.4.0/python/tests/test_note2midi.py", line 4, in <module>
from aubio import note2midi
ImportError: cannot import name note2midi
```

when I did a dir on aubio.

```
>>dir(aubio)
>>['__LICENSE__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'aubioclass', 'aubiowrapper', 'task']
```

I saw none of the functions included in demos and tests.

I was however, able to run scripts in ./aubio-master/python.old

Has anyone had similiar problems?

Answer (score 0):

I found that installing the 0.4 version of aubio was easiest using python module found on the site's download page.  Just unzip it and place the files in the right place.  The tar unzips to contain two folders, each mimicking the place where you probably keep your other python modules, usr/bin/ and /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/.  Try that, and before running the test, just try importing aubio from the python command line.